# Grails - Domain objects not saving in integration test

Tags: grails, integration-testing

I am following an example in the Grails In Action book. My integration test is failing because the searches in the example code are returning null references. I used a call to findAll() and now it appears my test data is not saving; all.size is coming back as zero.

```
void testBasicDynamicFinders() {

        new User(userId: 'glen', password: 'secret', profile: new Profile(email: 'glen@glensmith.com')).save()
        new User(userId: 'peter', password: 'sesame', profile: new Profile(homepage: 'http://www.peter.com/')).save()

        def all = User.findAll()
        assertEquals 2, all.size()
}
```

I have tried using save(flush: true) to no avail.

I have also enclosed one of the save statements in a try...catch structure, but no exception appears to be raised.

Grails is really kicking my butt. Please help me?

Comment: Have you tried `save( failOnError:true )`?

Comment: Aha! Doing this revealed that I had validation errors. Strange that the books doesn't mention any of this... Please submit your post as an answer so that I can accept it and give you proper recognition.

Comment: Done!  Thanks :-)  Yeah, validation errors are the usual culprit when things aren't saving

Comment: Oh, and in the book's defence, I discovered that I'd left out a line that made one of the fields nullable, and that's what caused the validation to fail. So my fault.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use

```
save( failOnError:true )
```

Then it should show you any validation errors that are preventing the domain objects from being saved :-)

Comment: This should be the default for any save attempts!